# facebook like live activity feed in android?

Tags: android, redis

I am working on an application which is expected to have a real time live activity feed on MainActivity.
I have worked with these things in Web but quite like a beginner in Android.

So what architecture would be best for this purpose ?

1. Have a timestamp for each activity feed and load the latest after pullToRefresh event.
2. Use a background service to pool server and a broadcast receiver to trigger events.
3. Using redis based pub/sub

Please help me to get new directions !

Answer (score 0):

You could use Socket.IO to get the new items in real-time instead of polling. It's a breeze to use with node and you can use this Android client: https://github.com/koush/android-websockets